# Can I start a new sprint without delivering the last one?

Tags: scrum-master

I'll try to simplify my questions and avoid story telling.

1) Can I start a new Sprint without delivering the last one?

2) During Sprint 2, can I include items into Sprint 1?

3) How many undeliverable Sprints can I have in my product?

I am facing a flexibility problem where the client says that he can change the framework any time and in any way he wants. He argues that Scrum predicts flexibility.

I'd like to know if there is a 'Scrum way' to deal with this, 'cause in the Scrum Guide I didn't find anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really trying to ask. "Change the framework at any time" certainly doesn't sound right, but replanning each Sprint is certainly an agile thing to do. What's the real problem you're trying to address?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs my real problem is deal with many undeliverable sprints.

Comment: What does it mean `During Sprint 2, can I include items into Sprint 1?` - that statement makes no sense. Sprint 1 is over when Sprint 2 starts. One team does not have concurrent Sprints.

Comment: Exactly @ThomasOwens. That is what I am suffering with the 'scrum flexibility'. I am asking and researching only to give a strong answer to my client.

Comment: Your team should not be running multiple Sprints concurrently. That concept doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz: Is there any possibility your client is regarding sprints as comparable to releases (or feature sets)?

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Can I start a new Sprint without delivering the last one?

It depends on what you mean by "deliver". If you are following Scrum, each Sprint results in a potentially shippable or releasable increment. That doesn't mean that each Sprint has to be shipped, released, or delivered to a customer.

> 2) During Sprint 2, can I include items from Sprint 1?

If you have unfinished work, then yes. The textbook answer is that, at the end of a Sprint, any Product Backlog Items selected for the Sprint are returned to the Product Backlog and the Product Owner can choose to reorder them appropriately. However, unless the priority has shifted, the result is often that they would "roll over" from one Sprint to the next.

> 3) How many undeliverable Sprints can I have in my product?

Zero undeliverable Sprints. The end result of every Sprint is supposed to be potentially shippable or releasable. However, you may have undelivered Sprints. That's a key distinction.

> I am facing a flexibility problem where the client says that he can
>   change the framework any time and in any way he wants. He argues that
>   Scrum predicts flexibility.
>
> I'd like to know if there is a 'Scrum way' to deal with this, 'cause
>   in the Scrum Guide I didn't find anything.

Scrum is a framework. It doesn't answer every question or address every situation that you may encounter. But it does often provide guidance. If there's nothing in [the Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/), you can always fall back to [the Manifesto for Agile Software Development](https://agilemanifesto.org/) and [its 12 principles](https://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html).

If you do break one of the rules in the Scrum framework, you are no longer doing Scrum. This isn't a bad thing. There are plenty of good ways of working that aren't Scrum, yet are still consistent with the values and principles of Agile Software Development and/or Lean Software Development and will result in successful projects and working relationships with stakeholders.

Comment: O correction in my question "During Sprint 2, can I include items INTO (not from) Sprint 1?"

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz What does that even mean?

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz: Sprints are periods in time. Your question amounts to essentially the same as asking if you can plan new work for week 31 in 2019, while today is in week 32 of the same year.

Answer (score 2):

First I'll answer your actual questions:

> Can I start a new sprint without delivering the last one?

Yes.

> During Sprint 2, can I include items into Sprint 1?

No. A Sprint is a timebox. It has a start-date, an end-date, and a Sprint Goal. Once the end-date has passed, the Sprint is done. Without a time machine, it's impossible to add more work into it at that point.

> How many undeliverable Sprints can I have in my product?

Hypothetically infinite.

Please note that, from the [Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-sprint) (emphasis mine):

> The heart of Scrum is a Sprint, a time-box of one month or less during which a "Done", useable, and **potentially** releasable product Increment is created.

At the end of every Sprint, your product should be in a state where you **could** release, **if you need to**. That doesn't mean that you **have to** release at any given time.

> how can possible many increment exists at same time?[sic]

They can't. Each increment is a Sprint, and each Sprint is a timebox, **not a collection of work**. You can't have two Sprints co-existing, because Sprint n must end before Sprint n+1 begins. Jan 5 cannot happen at the same time as Jan 6.

Also:

> I am facing a flexibility problem where the client says that he can change the framework any time and in any way he wants. He argues that Scrum predicts flexibility.

This seems to have nothing to do with an unreleased Sprint. Please either clarify or ask a separate Question.

Comment: About the 'flexibility problem' I'll remove from the question. Would you mind in tell us where in scrum guide your answers are based on? Do not misunderstand me. I am really confused about that.

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz I quote the relevant section, and link to it directly. The important word is 'potentially'. 'Each Sprint must be potentially releasable' and 'Each Sprint must be released' mean two very different things.

Comment: Thank you and I'll give a close attention.

Comment: Take a look at the develop team in scrum guide. The section starts wtih: "The Development Team consists of professionals who do the work of delivering a potentially releasable Increment of "Done" product at the end of each Sprint. A "Done" increment is required at the Sprint Review. Only members of the Development Team create the Increment." The sprint review should be at the last day of sprint right? Once said how can possible many increment exists at same time?

Comment: O correction in my question "During Sprint 2, can I include items INTO (not from) Sprint 1?"

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz Updated my Answer.